# Difference between limit() and $limit in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-stitch

inside my frontend and after authenticating a user, I have the following code that works:
..

```
...
.then(authedUser =>
        db
          .collection('comments')
          .find({}, { limit: 1 })
          .asArray()
      )
      .then(doc => console.log('doc:', doc)); // 1 doc returned as array, yes!
```

However, the following code doesn't work:
.

```
...
.then(authedUser =>
        db
          .collection('comments')
          .find({})
          .limit(1)
          .asArray()
      )
      .then(doc => console.log('doc:', doc)); // error inside Promise, limit is not a function...
```

May I know why? I know that limit() is a cursor method and $limit is an aggregate stage, so now I am a bit confused.

Comment: `asArray()` is correct for the SDK. This is using stitch so it's different from the driver.

Comment: Yes, I am using and referring to Stitch SDK.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little confusing in the docs because the second would work in a Stitch function but it doesn't work when using the SDK. The first is the correct way to do it from the SDK. In the SDK, a read operation doesn't have modifiers, which means you can't call `.limit()` on a `find()`.

Here are the [docs](https://s3.amazonaws.com/stitch-sdks/js/docs/4.1.0/interfaces/remotemongocollection.html#find) for what you're doing.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The funn part is the second one is allowed in Mongoose as i acreated a Api on Node , there is the code , worked perfectly fine

/// get all the full list

```
app.get("/expenses" , async(req,res) => {
    const page = Number(req.query.page) || 1
    const limit = Number(req.query.limit) || 5
    const skip =  (page - 1) * limit
    try {
       const stu = await Expense.find({}).limit(limit).skip(skip) ;  empty means all 
       res.status(200).json(stu)
    }catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
        res.status(500).json({message:err.message})
    }
     })
```